# Axios: How to intercept and respond to axios request

Tags: javascript, axios

Is there a way to not just intercept but also respond to an axios request before it has been sent off? As in, send a request from the browser and respond to it from the browser + prevent it from sending request.

I know that I can use `axios interceptors` to intercept the request and response before it is sent and  returned to the component and I know that in the request interceptor I can throw an error and trigger the response interceptor with a failed request. How can I do the same for a successful request? Given certain conditions I want axios to respond as if it passed to the server when it actually never made it past the interceptor. is this possible?

Here's pseudo code for what I've got so far:

```js
      axios.interceptors.request.use(
      request => {
        if (localResponse) {
              throw { isLocal: true, data: { hello: 'world' } }; // <- this will stop request and trigger 
                                                                 // response error. I want to trigger 
                                                                 // the actual response callback
        } else {
            return request;   // <- will perform full request
        }
      },
      error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      response => {
        return response; // <- I want to trigger this callback
      },
      error => { // <- so far i can only trigger a response error
        if (error?.isLocal) { 
          return Promise.resolve(error.data); 
        }
        
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
```

I've tried just resolving the request interceptor but that tries to continue to fulfill the request. Does anyone have any creative ideas for solving this problem? Maybe there's a better solution than using interceptors?

Comment: You could always use one of the _mock_ Axios libraries like jest-mock-axios or moxios in your production code. Just a thought ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I would view that as essentially a last option. I'm messing around with Electron and using axios essentially over HTTP and IPC and the only issue left is stopping the axios request, sending data over IPC instead and responding as if axios had completed request over HTTP.

Comment: I am having the same 'requirement' to response a request directly from the interceptor but it appears there is no easy built in solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Managed to compose a solution myself. This way all my axios calls will not have to be altered, i can just change behavior of interceptor.

NOTE: If anyone comes up with a better solution I will happily tag their answer as correct and upvote. For now this is the best solution I can come up with.

**SOLUTION**

Here's how i was able to resolve the problem

```js
      axios.interceptors.request.use(
      request => {
        if (localResponse) {
              throw { isLocal: true, data: { hello: 'world' } }; // <- this will stop request and trigger 
                                                                 // response error. I want to trigger 
                                                                 // the actual response callback
        } else {
            return request;   // <- will perform full request
        }
      },
      error => {
        return error?.isLocal 
                    ? Promise.resolve(error); // <- triggers response intercept
                    : Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );

    axios.interceptors.response.use(
      response => {
        return response; 
      },
      error => {
          error?.isLocal 
                ? Promise.resolve(error); // <- sends as successful response
                : Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
```

Essentially what I'm doing is throwing an error to prevent the request from going through, but then resolving the error instead of rejecting it. It's a little hacky but it gets the job done.

Comment: What a beautiful ugly hack :D

Comment: I ended up achieving the result by setting an adapter in the request interceptor, as mentioned in [this axios github issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1666#issuecomment-607625254). Feels like the right way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for linking to an additional solution @PepijnOlivier, it would be an additional service if you rewrote it here as a solution so people looking for answers can easily see it (and maybe upvote it).

Answer (score 1):

Can you just skip the request altogether in the local scenario?

```
function getData() {
  if (localResponse) {
    return Promise.resolve({ isLocal: true, data: { hello: 'world' }});
  }
  else {
    return axios.whatever;
  }
}
...
getData().then(...)
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get Promise.resolve to work without it sending the request which i want it to skip

Comment: In my example above, the request is sent in the `else` block, so it's impossible for it to send and call `Promise.resolve`.

Comment: You're right i miss read it. The issue here is that that solution requires me to alter an already exisiting structure and 'wraps' around axios instead of taking advantage of the already exisiting features. By using interceptors i'm able to add this feature without needing to modify all my axios code. For my particular problem, I can't make this kind of modification. Your answer did lead my to my own answer though, helpful for my brainstorming, so thank you;)

Answer (score 0):

You can provide custom [adapter](https://github.com/axios/axios/tree/main/lib/adapters)

```
import axios, { getAdapter } from 'axios';

const xhrAdapter = getAdapter('xhr');

axios.defaults.adapter = (config) => {
  if (useLocal) {
    return Promise.resolve({
      data: yourData,
      status: 200,
      statusText: 'ok',
      headers: {},
      config: config,
      request: {}
    });
  }
  return xhrAdapter(config)
}
```