# return response from vuejs route request interceptor

Tags: vue.js, axios

Is there a way on vuejs axios request interceptor instead of proceeding to http protocol I can just pass a response from within the request interceptor? say I want to just return a static value once certain conditions are not met when it was checked on the interceptor so no http request should occur then

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62686283/axios-how-to-intercept-and-respond-to-axios-request